# How do I iterate between 32 binary options?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an optimization problem where I have 5 variables: A, B1, B2, C1, C2. I am trying to optimize these 5 variables to get the smallest root sum square value I can. I have a few optimization techniques that are working ok, but this one in particular is giving me some trouble.

I want to explore all 32 options of changing the variables and pick the smallest RSS value. What I mean by this is each variable can either be +/- an increment. And each choice leads to 2 more choices, with 5 variables thats 32 choices. ( 2^5 )

To clarify, I am not adding my variables: A, B1, B2 etc to each other, I am     incrementing / decrementing them by an arbitrary amount. A +/- X, B1+/- X2, etc. And I am trying to figure out which combination of incrementation/ decrementation of my 5 variables will return the lowest Root sum square value.

```
                                   A
                                 +/ \-
                                B1   B1
                               +/\- +/\-
                              B2 B2 B2 B2
```

So on and so forth till all 5 levels are complete. I am not sure even where to start to attempt to solve this. What kind of data structure would be best for storing this? Is it an iterative, or a recursive solution. I don't need the answer to the problem, rather somewhere to look or somewhere to start. Thank you again for taking the time to look at this.

To clarify further confusion this is my optimization method. I ahve 5 variables, and 5 increments, each increment matches to a variable.
(a,b,c,d,e,f) ---> (incA, incB, incC, indD, incE, incF)

I want to find the best combination of +/- incX to X ( x being one of the 5 variables )ie:
the solution might be something like:
    a+incA , B-incB, c+incC, d+incD, e+incE, f-incF.
There are 32 possibilities of combinations, after reading through all the answers below I have settled on this possible algorithm. ( see my answer below ) make edits and questions as necessary. This is not a perfect algorithm, it is for clarification and ease of understanding, i know it can be condensed.

```
//Settign all possible solutions to be iterated through later.
double[] levelA = new double[2];
double[] levelB = new double[2];
double[] levelC = new double[2];
double[] levelD = new double[2];
double[] levelE = new double[2];

levelA[0] = a + incA;
levelA[1] = a - incA;
levelB[0] = b + incB;
levelB[1] = b - incB;
levelC[0] = c + incC;
levelC[1] = c - incC;
levelD[0] = d + incD;
levelD[1] = d - incD;
levelE[0] = e + incE;
levelE[1] = e - incE;

double[] rootSumAnswers = new double[32];
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j ++)
        {
            for(int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
            {
                for(int m = 0; m < 2; m++)
                {
                    rootSumAnswers[count++] = calcRootSum(levelA[i], levelB[k], levelC[j], levelD[n], levelE[m]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Finally, i find the minimum of my root sum squares and make that change permanent, and do this again.
```

Comment: I'm not sure where "root sum squere" is applied. Your tree looks like you're looking at the sum `A +/- B1 +/- B2 +/- C1 +/- C2` and are trying to figure out where to put a `+` and where to put a `-` to minimize that sum. Or are you actually looking at the sum `sqrt(A*A +/- B1*B1 ... +/- C2*C2)`?

Comment: Am I missing something or wouldn't the sum get smaller as the individual variables approach zero? So there wouldn't be a need to test all 32 possibilities, you can get away with testing 10.

Comment: check [this](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html) out. It is about binary search trees (BST).

Comment: The root sum square is used to evaluate which of the 32 options returns the best result. Which ever RSS value is the lowest of the 32 is the actualy choice I am going to use for iterating my variables. And I will look into the possibility of only testing 10, thank you

Comment: @kenetik sorry, but your explanation is still pretty confusing. Is that "arbitrary amount" fixed or variable? Please state the `actual` formula for the value you want to minimize in your question, and clearly state which variables are fixed, and which are to be optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can produce a set containing all possible sets of operations (e.g. {-,-,-,-}, {-,-,-,+}, {-,-,+,-} etc.) using the following function which will output a list of bool arrays where true and false represent + and -. The `vars` parameter indicates the number of variables being combined. Note that for 5 variables, there are only 16 combinations (not 32 as you state) since there are only 4 operators when combining 5 variables (assuming the first variable cannot be negated):

```
public List<bool[]> GetOperators(int vars)
{
    var result = new List<bool[]>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1 << vars-1; i++)
    {
        var item = new bool[vars - 1];
        for (var j = 0; j < vars-1; j++)
        {
            item[j] = ((i >> j) & 1) != 0;
        }
        result.Add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Once you have this list, you can use it to combine the variables in all possible ways. First we define a helper function to take a set of variables and a single `bool[]` combination and applies it (it assumes that there are the correct number of elements in the combination for the number of variables passed):

```
private double Combine(double[] vars, bool[] combination)
{
    var sum = vars[0];
    for (var i = 1; i< vars.Length; i++)
    {
        sum = combination[i - 1] ? sum + vars[i] : sum - vars[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You can also format the combination nicely using:

```
private string FormatCombination(double[] vars, bool[] combination)
{
    var result = vars[0].ToString("0.00##");
    for (var i = 1; i < vars.Length; i++)
    {
        result = string.Format("{0} {1} {2:0.00##}", result, combination[i - 1] ? "+" : "-", vars[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Putting it all together to test all possible combinations:

```
var vars = new []
{
    1.23, // A
    0.02, // B1
    0.11, // B2
    0.05, // C1
    1.26  // C2
};

foreach (var combination in GetOperators(vars.Length))
{
    var combined = Combine(vars, combination);

    // Perform your operations on "combined" here...

    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", FormatCombination(vars, combination), combined);
}
```

This will output:

```
1.23 - 0.02 - 0.11 - 0.05 - 1.26 = -0.21
1.23 + 0.02 - 0.11 - 0.05 - 1.26 = -0.17
1.23 - 0.02 + 0.11 - 0.05 - 1.26 = 0.01
1.23 + 0.02 + 0.11 - 0.05 - 1.26 = 0.05
1.23 - 0.02 - 0.11 + 0.05 - 1.26 = -0.11
1.23 + 0.02 - 0.11 + 0.05 - 1.26 = -0.07
1.23 - 0.02 + 0.11 + 0.05 - 1.26 = 0.11
1.23 + 0.02 + 0.11 + 0.05 - 1.26 = 0.15
1.23 - 0.02 - 0.11 - 0.05 + 1.26 = 2.31
1.23 + 0.02 - 0.11 - 0.05 + 1.26 = 2.35
1.23 - 0.02 + 0.11 - 0.05 + 1.26 = 2.53
1.23 + 0.02 + 0.11 - 0.05 + 1.26 = 2.57
1.23 - 0.02 - 0.11 + 0.05 + 1.26 = 2.41
1.23 + 0.02 - 0.11 + 0.05 + 1.26 = 2.45
1.23 - 0.02 + 0.11 + 0.05 + 1.26 = 2.63
1.23 + 0.02 + 0.11 + 0.05 + 1.26 = 2.67
```

---

**Edit:**

Per the changes to your question I have updated my answer. As others have mentioned, it may not be necessary to use a full search such as this, but you may find the method useful anyway.

`GetOperators()` changes slightly to return 2<sup>n</sup> combinations (rather than 2<sup>n-1</sup> as before):

```
public List<bool[]> GetOperators(int vars)
{
    var result = new List<bool[]>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1 << vars; i++)
    {
        var item = new bool[vars];
        for (var j = 0; j < vars; j++)
        {
            item[j] = ((i >> j) & 1) != 0;
        }
        result.Add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The `Combine()` method is changed to take a set of increments in addition to the variables and the combination to be used. For each element of the combination, if it is `true`, the increment is added to the variable, if it is false, it is subtracted:

```
private double[] Combine(double[] vars, double[] increments, bool[] combination)
{
    // Assuming here that vars, increments and combination all have the same number of elements
    var result = new double[vars.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = combination[i] ? vars[i] + increments[i] : vars[i] - increments[i];
    }

    // Returns an array of the vars and increments combined per the given combination
    // E.g. if there are 5 vars and the combination is: {true, false, true, true, false}
    // The result will be {var1 + inc1, var2 - inc2, var3 + inc3, var4 + inc4, var 5 - inc5}
    return result;
}
```

And `FormatCombination()` is also updated to display the new combination style:

```
private string FormatCombination(double[] vars, double[] increments, bool[] combination)
{
    var result = new List<string>(vars.Length);

    var combined = Combine(vars, increments, combination);

    for (var i = 0; i < vars.Length; i++)
    {
        result.Add(string.Format("{0:0.00##} {1} {2:0.00##} = {3:0.00##}", vars[i], combination[i] ? "+" : "-", increments[i], combined[i]));
    }
    return string.Join(", ", result.ToArray());
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
var vars = new[]
{
    1.23, // A
    0.02, // B
    0.11, // C
    0.05, // D
    1.26, // E
};

var increments = new[]
{
    0.04, // incA
    0.11, // incB
    0.01, // incC
    0.37, // incD
    0.85, // incD
};

foreach (var combination in GetOperators(vars.Length))
{
    var combined = Combine(vars, increments, combination);

    // Perform operation on combined here...

    Console.WriteLine(FormatCombination(vars, increments, combination));
}
```

Output (abridged):

```
1.23 - 0.04 = 1.19, 0.02 - 0.11 = -0.09, 0.11 - 0.01 = 0.10, 0.05 - 0.37 = -0.32, 1.26 - 0.85 = 0.41
1.23 + 0.04 = 1.27, 0.02 - 0.11 = -0.09, 0.11 - 0.01 = 0.10, 0.05 - 0.37 = -0.32, 1.26 - 0.85 = 0.41
1.23 - 0.04 = 1.19, 0.02 + 0.11 = 0.13, 0.11 - 0.01 = 0.10, 0.05 - 0.37 = -0.32, 1.26 - 0.85 = 0.41
1.23 + 0.04 = 1.27, 0.02 + 0.11 = 0.13, 0.11 - 0.01 = 0.10, 0.05 - 0.37 = -0.32, 1.26 - 0.85 = 0.41
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, Your solution works perfectly, however due to my poor explanation it was not what I was looking for. I aplologize for the miss interpretation of the question, I re-edited my question. I am adding an arbitrary increment to each of my 5 variables, not the 5 variables to each other. Thank you though for this algorithm.

Comment: @kenetik I have updated my answer based on the changes to your question.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to current version of the question

You don't need to do any search at all here. For each variable, pick the sign (+ or -) for which `A +/- incA` has the smallest absolute value (in other words the sign which produces the smallest *square* of `A +/- inc A`). This minimizes all terms in the sum-of-squares, and hence minimized the whole sum.

### Previous answer

Assuming that you want to minimize `sqrt(A*A +/- B1*B1 +/- B2*B2 +/- C1*C1 +/- C2*C2)` by picking suitable signs `+` or `-`, simply iterate over the 32 possible combinations, and pick the one which yields the smallest result. To iterate over all the combinations, observe that if you iterate over the integers 0 to 31, and look at their binary representations, you'll find *all* combinations of 5 zeros and ones. Further observe that you can find out whether a particular integer n contains 1 at the binary digit k, you just have to check if the bitwise and of n and k-th power of 2 is non-zero. In pseudo-code, you therefore do

```
min_sign_a = 1
min_sign_b1 = 1
min_sign_b2 = 1
min_sign_c1 = 1
min_sign_c2 = 1
min_sum = a*a + b1*b1 + b2*b2 + c1*c1 + c2*c2
for(i in 1,...,31)
  sign_a = (i & 1) ? -1 : 1
  sign_b1 = (i & 2) ? -1 : 1
  sign_b2 = (i & 4) ? -1 : 1
  sign_c1 = (i & 8) ? -1 : 1
  sign_c2 = (i & 16) ? -1 : 1
  sum = sign_a*a*a + sign_b1*b1*b1 + sign_b2*b2*b2 + sign_c1*c1*c1 + sign_c2*c2*c2
  if (sum < min_sum)
    min_sign_a = sign_a
    min_sign_b1 = sign_b1
    min_sign_b2 = sign_b2
    min_sign_c1 = sign_c1
    min_sign_c2 = sign_c2
  end
end
```

Here, "&" stand for bitwise-and. A one in the k-th bit of i gives the k-th variable a negative sign, a zero gives it a positive sign. The case "i = 0", i.e. all signs are positive as handled before the loop starts, to avoid having to deal with `min_sum` not being initialized in the first run of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, Your solution works perfectly, however due to my poor explanation it was not what I was looking for. I aplologize for the miss interpretation of the question, I re-edited my question. I am adding an arbitrary increment to each of my 5 variables, not the 5 variables to each other. Thank you though for this algorithm

Comment: Also, what if he decides to switch to more or fewer variables?

Comment: Lol, what if he wants an arbitrary number of variables? I think it's probably better to have the structure of the code agnostic of the number of variables.

Comment: @sshannin Why? Complexity for complexity's sake buys you nothing. If your problem is to optimize 5 variables, code for 5. Unless you already *know* that it'll be 6 tomorrow, 4 in a week, and eventually be 20. This is especially true here, where anything over 20 or so variables won't work anyway, because the runtime rises exponentially. So really, what's to point of a generic algorithm that breaks down for N >= 20 anyway?

Comment: I agree with your main point. But I don't really think the generic case is any more difficult to code or understand...In fact, I think it's much clearer than your bit-hacking.

Comment: @sshannin I respectfully disagree. *Conceptually*, looping over 32 cases is much simpler than a recursive method which uses two stacks to track it's state. Plus, the bit-hacking can be easily cleaned up a bit by using an array instead of those separate sign variables. It'd even support an arbitrary number of variables then (well, for small values of "arbitrary", at least...). The most readable solution, btw, is probably just 5 nested loops ;-).

Comment: Hah, fair enough. The way I did it is much more natural to me (obviously). Whatever works best for you I guess : p

Answer (score 1):

Since my first answer was deleted since it was pseudocode instead of c#...I changed my abstract set into a stack...

I think a nice recursive approach works:

```
int FindBest(int increment, Stack<int> decided_vars, Stack<int> free_vars)
{
  if free_vars.size() == 0
  {
     return PerformCalculation(decided_vars);
  }

  int new_element = free_vars.Pop()
  new_element += increment;

  //check one case
  decided_vars.Push(new_element)
  int result1 = FindBest(increment, decided_vars, free_vars)

  //reset sets for second case
  decided_vars.Pop();
  new_element -= 2 * increment;
  decicded_vars.Push(new_element);
  int result2 = FindBest(increment, decided_vars, free_vars);

  //reset sets as they were to give back to parent
  decided_vars.Pop()
  free_vars.Push( new_element + increment )

  return max(result1, result2);
}
```

You can define PerformCalculation as the function you want to maximize/minimize.

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt know your first answer was deleted, I didn't even get a chance to see it. I will look over this one carefully, thank you for your input

Comment: I adjusted my answer to do the +/- adjustments by a specificed increment as you added to your question.

Answer (score 1):

A good method to optimize several parameters is the [Nelder–Mead method or Downhill Simplex method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method). It "walks" through the parameter space in a quite natural way, without testing every permutation. See also [Downhill Simplex method](http://www.is.doshisha.ac.jp/report/2006/9/25/20060806006/index.html) (with good graphics showing the principle).

I also found a [code in C#](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid218B2E3946027CB5037676EA50CE549B6FC26CF7.aspx?s=search); however, I didn't test it.